# Display message based on cart items count in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, count, cart

I'd like to display a message in either `woocommerce_before_cart` or
`woocommerce_before_cart_table` if the total number of items in the cart is less than X, and also display the difference. By items I mean individual quantities not product lines.

How can I add a function that sums the quantities of all items in the cart and displays a message if the total is less than the specified quantity?

Example: Set the number to 30, cart contains a total of 27 items, so a message would say 'If you order 3 more items you can get...' etc. But if the cart already has 30 or more items, then no message needs to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a custom message on cart page based on number of cart items count, use the following:

```
// On cart page only
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'custom_total_item_quantity_message' );
function custom_total_item_quantity_message() {
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $min_count   = 30;

    if( is_cart() && $items_count < $min_count ){
        wc_print_notice( sprintf( __("If you order %s more items you can get…", "woocommerce"), $min_count - $items_count ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

If using `woocommerce_before_cart` or `woocommerce_before_cart_table` the remaining count will not be updated when changing quantities or removing items… Try:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'custom_total_item_quantity_message' );
function custom_total_item_quantity_message() {
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $min_count   = 30;

    if( is_cart() && $items_count < $min_count ){
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">';
        printf( __("If you order %s more items you can get…", "woocommerce"), $min_count - $items_count );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

or:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'custom_total_item_quantity_message' );
function custom_total_item_quantity_message() {
    $items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    $min_count   = 30;

    if( is_cart() && $items_count < $min_count ){
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-info">';
        printf( __("If you order %s more items you can get…", "woocommerce"), $min_count - $items_count );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the message always says 'order x more items' and the x is the current cart items total (so says 29 if I have 29 items). It should be the difference between the min items and the current cart items total (so should say 1). Also how can I add this message specifically in woocommerce_before_cart or woocommerce_before_cart_table as mentioned rather than as a notice? Thanks

Comment: @Lyall Sorry I have updated my code, I didn't pay attention… Now you can't add it as you would like in `woocommerce_before_cart` or `woocommerce_before_cart_table`, because if you update cart items changing quantities or removing items, it will not be reflected on the remaining count.

Comment: Thank you that's great I've accepted the answer. Is the issue I'm having with the notice being displayed twice on cart-reload specific to my individual set-up, mostly likely because I have cart and checkout on the same page? https://i.postimg.cc/Gp2gYnvQ/Notice.png

Comment: @Lyall I have added the necessary version code for `woocommerce_before_cart` or `woocommerce_before_cart_table`… so you can try it.

Comment: Thanks, I added it to woocommerce_before_cart and it does update the qty when the cart reloads and also only shows once :) thanks!