# Display message if any cart item has quantity of 1 in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, woocommerce

This is similar to a question I posted previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905374/display-message-based-on-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce-cart) but the calculation I need for a new project is different.

Rather than showing a notice based on the total quantity of items in the cart, I need to show a notice if any one product in the cart has a quantity of 1. If no items in the cart have a quantity of 1 then it doesn't need to show, but if any item does then it needs to show. Is this possible?

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I can't share everything I've tried as I've spent ages getting it wrong... I'll add an update later with what I currently have :)

Comment: @Lyall Please post your solution as an answer rather than an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function loops over cart items, if quantity of a cart item is equal to 1 the notice is shown and the function ends.

```
   function display_notice_based_on_item_quantity() {

       foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {    
            if ( $cart_item['quantity'] == 1 )
            {
                if ( is_cart() )
                    wc_print_notice( sprintf( __("there is an item with qunatity of 1 in the cart", "woocommerce") ), 'notice' );
                break;
            }
       } 

    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'display_notice_based_on_item_quantity' );
```

You can use 'woocommerce_check_cart_items' hook, or other cart hooks based on where you need to print the notice.

Here is also a modified answer to exclude products in certain category  from triggering the notice (question from comment):

```
function display_notice_based_on_item_quantity() {

   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['quantity'] == 1 )
        {
            $terms = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
            foreach ( $terms as $term )
            {
               if ($term->slug == 'your-category-slug')
                    continue 2;
            }
            if ( is_cart() )
                wc_print_notice( sprintf( __("there is an item with qunatity of 1 in the cart", "woocommerce") ), 'notice' );
            break;
        }
   } 

}
```

Whenever a product with quantity 1 is found, there is another nested loop that iterates over the product's categories, if any of the categories matches the one that you don't want to trigger the notice then notice is not displayed and the outer loop continues.

Don't forget to replace 'your-category-slug' with slug of the category you don't want to trigger the notice.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can exclude products in a certain category from triggering it? I.e. loop over all cart items that aren't in a specified category?

Comment: I will edit the answer to fulfill this requirement as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in the end, thanks to mpx9910's answer (thank you!):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents', 'display_notice_based_on_item_quantity' );
function display_notice_based_on_item_quantity() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {    
            if ( $cart_item['quantity'] == 1 )
            {
             $terms = get_the_terms( $cart_item['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
             foreach ( $terms as $term )
                {
                if ($term->slug == 'your-category-slug')
                    continue 2;
                }
                if ( is_cart() )
                    echo '<div class="cart-qty-notice">';
                    printf( __("Message goes here", "woocommerce"));
                    echo '</div>';
                break;
            }
       }
    }
```