# Display message based on cart items count in WooCommerce mini cart

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added a static message inside WooCommerce mini cart with the following snippet, it appears right before the Checkout button:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total', 'my_custom_text', 15 );
function my_custom_text() {
  print '<p class="mini_cart_text">TEXT HERE</p>';  
}
```

I would like to make this text dynamic based on cart items count:

- Cart items < 2 = text one
- Cart items > 2 = text two

I tried to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905374/display-message-based-on-cart-items-count-in-woocommerce-cart) as a starting point by changing the initial part of the add_action with  woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total that is where I want this text to appear.

I have used all the 3 examples gently provided but unfortunately nothing appears and I have no idea why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_total', 'bbloomer_minicart_custom_text', 15 );

function bbloomer_minicart_custom_text() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart ) return;
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > 2 ) {
        echo '<p class="mini_cart_text">TEXT TWO</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p class="mini_cart_text">TEXT ONE</p>';
    }
}
```

*** Before testing the mini-cart again, please empty the Cart or update the quantity of one item in the Cart, so that the Cart cache is cleared.